# Scheduling & Routing Optimization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, shortest-path

I am having the following optimization problem setup:

**Given:**

about 100 Mechanics, each with

- Work time per day [e.g. 8 hours]
- Break time per day [e.g. min 1 hour]
- Maximum overtime per day [e.g. 1 hour]
- Location [e.g. Detroit]

about 1000 Tasks, each with

- Location [e.g. Chicago]
- Duration [e.g. 1 hour]
- Fixed time slot [e.g. 1pm] [optional]

The goal is to schedule all tasks to the mechanics with short paths. One constraint is that every mechanic starts & ends at his home location.

Is there any way to solve this problem in an easy & understandable way? Are there any similar examples online in e.g. python?

Answer (score 1):

Not all workers would be available to do a task because of Location. If Locations don't overlap, you could at least segment the problem into Location-specific one to avoid dealing with it. Then you could assign the fixed timeslots first, always picking the workers with the least hours on the schedule. Since hours are a discrete value, you could pick the nearest worker by distance when choosing a worker amongst several that have an equal number of scheduled hours.

This would be a very basic approach that would do the scheduling but may not do it in a practical manner - for example, two close-by jobs may be assigned to different workers and efficiency may not be good at all when you consider travel time between jobs. You would have to iterate with the business and apply some heuristics to get to a usable solution.
I'd advise you to get a real-world sample of the input data - availability, locations, jobs etc - as large as possible, and create some evaluation function first: overtime, travel time, utilization of the workforce should all factor in, then you could see what heuristics need to be applied to the basic algorithm.

Another approach would be to cluster the jobs by location, into 1-worker-per-day clusters, and assign close-by jobs to the same worker. Look into graph clustering algorithms for that. Within a cluster you could assign the fixed-time jobs first, then the rest in random order. You could also limit the clusters to not have overlapping fixed-time jobs.

Either way, you'll have to come up with heuristics, whichever approach you take.

Finding the optimal solution may be an NP-hard problem [http://www.cs.mun.ca/~kol/courses/6901-f14/lec3.pdf](http://www.cs.mun.ca/%7Ekol/courses/6901-f14/lec3.pdf)